# Shrink Details section height MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a a report from code in Access. However, after the report is created, the height of the details section seemed to be set to be 3.5 Inches where i really just need it to be a small height.

I've tried researching online and it returns results such as `Me.detail.height = 500` or `detail.height = 500` and even `detail.autoheight = true`

At the end of the day, the report generated still had a height of 3.5 Inches. After the report is generated, i am able to shift the bar manually up, so there is definitely no other controls taking up space at the bottom of the details area.

Can anyone enlighten me on this trivial issue? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found the right property to edit, although if it's on report generation you should set it up in design mode and not bother with VBA: the height property should only be changed programatically on the report if you have a button or something where you want to edit things after the report has already generated.

---

Other things to consider:

The height is in twips, which is 1440 twips per inch, if that gives you an idea of what numbers the height should be.

Secondly, the details section repeats for each record. So, if you have a height of 500 and 10 records you'll end up with a height of 5000 which is roughly 3.5 inches. There is no value which is the combined height of all Detail sections, especially due to group by headers and footers/ totalling etc.

Remember that the Detail section repeats for each record, for me I usually shrink it down to only 1 line tall.

EDIT: to change the detail programatically (assuming you already are using a report object)

```
reportObject.Section(acDetail).Height
```

allows you to edit the height of the detail section before the report is even created

Comment: This is really helpful thanks! I cant do it in design mode because each time the report is generated, it would actually be a different report, depending on parameters from users. So say that i really need to do this programmtically, how should i do it? what should i change?

Comment: Ah I see what you are asking. 
I will update my answer accordingly